# Как лучше хранить данные в базе типа ['2004', 1000, 400],

Tags: база-данных, php, mysql

как мне лучше хранить значения в базе что бы потом просто через for или foreach вывести значения в таком виде: есть таблица bank и допустим поле charts какого оно типа, и как хранить...

```
data.addRows([
      ['2004', 1000, 400],
      ['2005', 1170, 460],
      ['2006',  860, 580],
      ['2007', 1030, 540]
    ]);

function drawChart() {
    var data = new google.visualization.DataTable();
    data.addColumn('string', 'Year');
    data.addColumn('number', 'Sales');
    data.addColumn('number', 'Expenses');
    data.addRows([
      ['2004', 1000, 400],
      ['2005', 1170, 460],
      ['2006',  860, 580],
      ['2007', 1030, 540]
    ]);

    var options = {
      width: 400, height: 240,
      title: 'Company Performance'
    };

    var chart = new google.visualization.LineChart(document.getElementById('chart_div'));
    chart.draw(data, options);
  }
```

Answer (score 1):

Гм... Ну, закиньте все в int'ы. А потом сгенерируете js-код с помощью php:

```
var dataRows = [
      <?/*вывод данных*/?>
    ];
data.addRows(dataRows);

function drawChart() {
    var data = new google.visualization.DataTable();
    data.addColumn('string', 'Year');
    data.addColumn('number', 'Sales');
    data.addColumn('number', 'Expenses');
    data.addRows(dataRows);
    ...
```